# Split audio by repeated short sound

Tags: sound

I have a long mp3 audio file in which a particular short sound repeats. Is it possible in Mathematica to split the initial mp3 file into several mp3 files that end by this short delimiting sound?

Here are the exemplary files for the [whole audio](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wVkDoy7MgVnjHVsBb4zb6CEzAX4fWLqz/view) and the [delimiter sound](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1csVpKRLp_ZZR_z0tEi7DLAagT7WbuCnI/view).

Comment: When you do the correlation, you may want to consider using AudioMFCC (or some other way of extracting features from the audio) rather than the audio itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NEW METHOD:**

This is much quicker. Final result as a list of partitioned audios is stored in `saudio` .

(By the way the dictionary is really reliable - it translates `огонь` as `wire` instead of `fire` :-D)

```
aud = ImportByteArray[
   ByteArray[
    Join[Flatten[
      Round[(ImageData[Import[#]][[All, All, 
             1]])*255] & /@ {"https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtqLu.png", 
        "https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW5q6.png", 
        "https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVYL0.png", 
        "https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNAUu.png"}]]], "MP3"];
del = ImportByteArray[
   ByteArray[
    Join[Flatten[
       Round[(ImageData[Import[#]][[All, All, 
              1]])*255] & /@ \
{"https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1j5L.png"}]][[1 ;; -4]]], "MP3"];

le = QuantityMagnitude@AudioLength[del];

alm = AudioLocalMeasurements[aud, "RMSAmplitude", 
   PartitionGranularity -> Quantity[le, "Samples"]];
par = Partition[
   Join[{0}, 
    Flatten[{# - 0.2, # + 0.2} & /@ 
      Select[FindPeaks[alm, 0] // Normal, 
        0.005 < #[[2]] < 0.02 &][[All, 1]]], {QuantityMagnitude[
      Duration[aud], "Seconds"]}], 2];
saudio = AudioTrim[aud, #] & /@ par;
```

---

**OLD METHOD:**

All the computation (correlation) is done by:

```
vys = {};
Do[dif = (daud[[1, n + 1 ;; n + le2]] - ddel[[1]]) // Abs // Total; 
 If[dif < 380, AppendTo[vys, {n, dif}]], {n, 1, le1 - le2}]
vys
```

where `daud` is audio data of `test.mp3` and `ddel` is audio data of `delimiter.mp3`. Variable `vys` contains positions of all delimiter sounds and can be seen as list output down bellow.

Since Mathematica's `ListCorrelate` sucks in performance if used with custom functions (fifth and sixth argument of the function) I had to use good-old `Do` which overcome `ListCorrelate` by several magnitudes, yet still it took 12 minutes to do the `Do` cycle.

Yes, it is ridiculous that it takes 3:47 minutes to play the whole sound and computation takes almost four times more.

```
(*aud=Import["C:\\...\\test.mp3"];
del=Import["C:\\...\\delimiter.mp3"];*)

aud = ImportByteArray[
   ByteArray[
    Join[Flatten[
      Round[(ImageData[Import[#]][[All, All, 
             1]])*255] & /@ {"https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtqLu.png", 
        "https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW5q6.png", 
        "https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVYL0.png", 
        "https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNAUu.png"}]]], "MP3"];
del = ImportByteArray[
   ByteArray[
    Join[Flatten[
       Round[(ImageData[Import[#]][[All, All, 
              1]])*255] & /@ \
{"https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1j5L.png"}]][[1 ;; -4]]], "MP3"];

daud = AudioData[aud];
ddel = AudioData[del];
ddel = ddel/Max[ddel[[1]]];
le1 = daud[[1]] // Length;
le2 = ddel[[1]] // Length;

vys = {};
Do[dif = (daud[[1, n + 1 ;; n + le2]] - ddel[[1]]) // Abs // Total; 
 If[dif < 380, AppendTo[vys, {n, dif}]], {n, 1, le1 - le2}]
vys

pos = (SortBy[#, #[[2]] &] & /@ 
     Gather[vys, Abs[First@#1 - First@#2] < le2/2 &])[[All, 1, 1]];

Partition[Join[{1}, Flatten[{#, # + le2} & /@ pos], {le1}], 2];
AudioTrim[
   aud, {Quantity[#[[1]], "Samples"], 
    Quantity[#[[2]], "Samples"]}] & /@ 
 Partition[Join[{1}, Flatten[{#, # + le2} & /@ pos], {le1}], 2]
```

---

{121101,350616,580313,809835,1039339,1268895,1498431,1727917,1957611,2187133,2415123,2649062,2878614,3108288,3337810,3567318,3796869,4026366,4255889,4485586,4715110,4944615,5174180,5403663,5633189,5862885,6092408,6321905,6551419,6780961,7010485,7240181,7469704,7699205,7928716,8158296,8387783,8617480,8847001,9076505,9306015,9535568,9765081,9994777}

The code produces list that contains positions of delimiters in sample units and list of partitions of the original audio without delimiter sound.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can try correlating your audio with the short sound by using [`ListCorrelate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCorrelate.html), then find peaks with [`FindPeaks`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindPeaks.html) and split the audio with [`AudioSplit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AudioSplit.html).

```
(* Sound to be repeated *)
sound = AudioGenerator[{"Sin", Quantity[2000, "Hertz"]}, 
   Quantity[0.5, "Seconds"]];

(* Audio (repeated sound + noise) *)
audio = AudioJoin @@ (Riffle[Table[sound, {4}], 
     Table[AudioGenerator["Silence", 
       Quantity[RandomReal[{.5, 3}], "Seconds"]], {4}], {1, -1, 2}]);
audio += .1 AudioGenerator["White", Duration[audio]];

(* Correlate sound and audio *)
corr = First[ListCorrelate[AudioData[sound], AudioData[audio]]]^2;
corr = LowpassFilter[corr, 1/20];

(* Find peaks *)
peaks = FindPeaks[corr, 20, 5];

(* Split audio *)
splitted = AudioSplit[audio, ((First /@ peaks) + 
    AudioSampleRate[audio] Duration[sound])/AudioSampleRate[audio]]

AudioPlot[audio]
AudioPlot /@ splitted
```

[image]

The code here serves just as an example. Obviously, there are parameters to be tuned for your actual audio.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't function in my situation, likely because of louder speech interference between the delimiter sounds.

Comment: @ФилиппЦветков, well, it is quite difficult to provide a helpful feedback without an example of your sounds ... :)

Comment: I know, but I did not find how I can attach mp3 files here...

Comment: Upload them to some other file-sharing service and paste the link.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1csVpKRLp_ZZR_z0tEi7DLAagT7WbuCnI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wVkDoy7MgVnjHVsBb4zb6CEzAX4fWLqz/view?usp=sharing